# Web API Post giving me error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API application. I'm supposed to do a post to an endpoint. When l tried my API controller in postman, l get the error message "

> Requested resource does not support HTTP 'POST'

I'm new to Web API so any help and suggestions are welcomed.

This is my model class:

```
     namespace Products.Models
      {
         public class Prouct

          {

         public string ProductID { get; set; }
         public string ProductName { get; set; }
         public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
         public string VoucherID { get; set; }

          }
        }
```

Here is my controller class

```
[RoutePrefix("api/products")]

public class ProductsController : ApiController
 {


        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }


    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    [Route("products")]
    public async Task PostAsync(string ProductID, string ProductName, string ProductPrice,
        string VoucherID)
    {

        Products p = new Products();
        p.ProductID = ProductID;
        p.ProductName = ProductName;
        p.ProductPrice = ProductPrice;
        p.VoucherID = VoucherID;

        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new 
                   Uri("http://localhost:51613/") };
        var response = await 
        client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", 
        p);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

        }

     public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }


    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `HttpPost` on `PostAsync` method. by default, it is `[HttpGet]`.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("products")]
public async Task PostAsync(string ProductID, string ProductName, string ProductPrice, string VoucherID)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're stuck in a loop. Why does the PostAsync method call itself after having been invoked? This will result in an endless request loop.

```
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51613/") };
```

This is not related to the fact that the [HttpPost] attribute is required however.

Answer (score 0):

Please observe that you are supposed to use [FromBody] . Also inside Postman (image attached) you have to choose "Raw" data with the product json with type as JSON(application.json).

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("products")]       
    public  async Task  PostAsync([FromBody] Products p)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new
                   Uri("http://localhost:51613/")
        };
        var response = await
        client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products",
        p);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

        }

    }
```

[image: Postman]